# How to control the folder where Jupyter Notebook saves the ipynb files

Tags: python-3.x, windows, directory, jupyter-notebook, save

I am using Windows 10 and I start Jupyter Notebook by navigating to a folder named: Jupyter_Notebook_Files and then executing the command: jupyter notebook.

While this folder is populated with ipynb files there are Jupyter Notebooks I have created that are not to be found there, rather they are located in a different folder named Mint.

How can I make Jupyter Notebook to save all my ipynb files --i.e. all the Jupyter Notebooks I create and modify/copy-- to the same directory i.e. Jupyter_Notebook_Files?

Comment: you can execute jupyter from this "Jupyter_Notebook_Files" folder every time and it will save in this location only.

Comment: This was my understanding.  Now I am thinking about it more carefully, perhaps I did not press the save button after I renamed the Jupyter Notebook.  JN does not have an autosave feature like e.g. Word?

Comment: JN DOES have autosave feature.

Comment: Here is some advice that will be helpful. It is as much for readers considering helping as it is for you. (1) you are probably asking too many questions. Eight posts in two days means that you are not waiting for answers on one thing before jumping to the next thing. This would further indicate to me that you are not doing the necessary research. (2) You are adding chatty material about appreciating help, even though many editors have removed this from your prior posts. Technical writing is an expectation here. Meta references are available on request.